# Jersey Client Throws IllegalStateException : Client instance has been closed

Tags: java, spring-boot, jersey-2.0

In Spring boot project, Created Bean for Jersey client and using it from multiple place. here is the bean defination:

```html
@Bean
public Client client() {
    return ClientBuilder.newClient()
    .property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5000)
    .property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 5000);
}
```

Getting error whenever jersey client tries to build new resource target (WebTarget). The problem is that It is throwing IllegalStateException while calling target(uri) method.

```
Response response = client.target(TARGET_URI).request().get():
String[] res= response.readEntity(String.class).split("\\|");
```

Error-

```html
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Client instance has been closed.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.guava.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.checkNotClosed(JerseyClient.java:257)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:272)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:56)
    at com.nobroker.notification.api.service.notification.impl.sms.GupshupSMSProvider.lambda$sendSMS$0(GupshupSMSProvider.java:90)
    at com.nobroker.notification.util.Retrier.connectExceptionRetry(Retrier.java:46)
    at com.nobroker.notification.api.service.notification.impl.sms.GupshupSMSProvider.sendSMS(GupshupSMSProvider.java:90)
    at com.nobroker.notification.api.service.notification.impl.sms.GupshupSMSProvider.send(GupshupSMSProvider.java:65)
    at com.nobroker.notification.api.service.notification.impl.BaseNotificationProvider.processNotification(BaseNotificationProvider.java:35)
    at com.nobroker.notification.api.service.NotificationMgr._sendNotification(NotificationMgr.java:108)
    at com.nobroker.notification.api.service.NotificationMgr.sendNotification(NotificationMgr.java:91)
    at com.nobroker.notification.kafka.consumers.notification.NotificationKafkaConsumer.consumeEvent(NotificationKafkaConsumer.java:41)
    at com.nobroker.notification.kafka.consumers.base.BaseEventConsumer.lambda$processRecords$0(BaseEventConsumer.java:75)
    at com.nobroker.notification.kafka.consumers.base.BaseEventConsumer$BlockingExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BaseEventConsumer.java:145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```